# What is this texture map used for?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I downloaded a model with all the texture maps and I've never seen one like this before. What is it, and what is it used for? Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Is the texture named? Some engines use channel packing - each RGB channel contains a different BW texture which could give similarly weird result when combined ;)

Comment: Could be used for material ID or object ID mapping...

Comment: The name for these textures are 
- T_palm_tree06_D.tga for the diffuse
- T_palm_tree06_N.tga for normal map
-T_palm_tree06_M.tga for the one shown here